# WCF + REST, Increase MaxStringContentLength

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-rest, webchannelfactory

We are running into the following error:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type
>   Project.ModelType. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has
>   been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by
>   changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

There are a ton of articles, forum posts, etc., showing how to increase the `MaxStringContentLength` size for a WCF service. The problem I'm experiencing is that all of these examples use Binding, which we do not use. We have no bindings or endpoint configurations set up in the `web.config` of our service project. We are using .cs files, not .svc files. We have implemented RESTful WCF services.

On the client side, we are using `WebChannelFactory` to call our services.

ASP.NET 4.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you **show us** your server-side `web.config` and the code on the client to create the proxy??

Comment: Where is the error showing up? At the client or the server?

Comment: The error is on the server side when it attempts to deserialize the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a binding, it's just that the `WebChannelFactory` is setting it up for you automatically. It turns out that this factory always creates an endpoint with a `WebHttpBinding`, so you can change the binding properties before creating the first channel from it - see the example below.

```
public class StackOverflow_7013700
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetString(int size);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string GetString(int size)
        {
            return new string('r', size);
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new WebChannelFactory<ITest>(new Uri(baseAddress));
        (factory.Endpoint.Binding as WebHttpBinding).ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 100000;
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetString(100).Length);

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetString(60000).Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", e.GetType().FullName, e.Message);
        }

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```